# Using custom registered locator in Playwright doesn't return any items

Tags: c#, .net, playwright

Using .NET 6 + Specflow + NUnit + Playwright to run E2E tests on UI.

I'm moving away from selectors declared in an .xml file, instead I want to use built-in Playwright locators and custom ones.

We have lots of "formcontrolname", "class" and other attributes which can be used to find an element in DOM, however following the steps here: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/api/class-selectors#selectors-register
doesn't work, no items are returned.

My implementation (before creating a page object is):

```
private static async Task RegisterCustomLocators(params string[] locators)
        {
            foreach (var locator in locators)
            {
                await _playwright.Selectors.RegisterAsync(locator, new SelectorsRegisterOptions
                {
                    Script = @"{
                                    // Returns the first element matching given selector in the root's subtree.
                                    query(root, selector) {
                                        return root.querySelector(selector);
                                    },
                                    // Returns all elements matching given selector in the root's subtree.
                                    queryAll(root, selector) {
                                        return Array.from(root.querySelectorAll(selector));
                                    }
                                }"
                });
            }
        }
```

Then I try to use it like this:

```
await ValidateElementEnabled(_page.Locator("formcontrolname=test123"));
```

But when I do CountAsync Locator object returned from
`_page.Locator("formcontrolname=test123")` I get 0.

Using below string selector works perfectly:

```
await ValidateElementEnabled(_page.Locator("//mat-select[@formcontrolname='test123'"));
```

Is the init script wrong or my selectors are?